# want the another database column's sum in another view page

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I created a question for answers and set 1 mark if answers is correct.. and the total of that column will be displayed in another page.. please help me out

```
def next
@ans_id = 1
@user = current_user
@student = Student.find_by_admission_no(@user.username)
@exam_group = ExamGroup.find_by_id(params[:exam_group_id])
@answer = Answer.new(params[:ans])
@answer.answer = params[:answer]
@answer.exam_group_id = @exam_group.id
@answer.user_id = @user.id
passed_question = params[:passed_question]
@answer.questions_id = passed_question
@question = Question.find_by_id(passed_question)
if params[:answer] == @question.is_answer
  @answer.marks = 1
else
  @answer.marks = 0
end
if @answer.save
  @ans_id = @ans_id + answered.count
  @ans = Question.find_by_id(left_random, :conditions => ['id not in (?) && exam_group_id=?',answered, @exam_group])
  render(:update) do |page|
    page.replace_html 'main', :partial => 'ans', :object => @ans
  end
end
end
```

and the database is

```
+----+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+-------+
| id | answer | questions_id | user_id | exam_group_id | modules_id | marks |
+----+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+-------+
|  1 | ans1   |            1 |       3 |             1 |       NULL |     1 |
|  2 | ans2   |            2 |       3 |             1 |       NULL |     1 |
|  3 | ans3   |            3 |       3 |             1 |       NULL |     0 |
|  4 | ans2   |            4 |       3 |             1 |       NULL |     0 |
+----+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+-------+
```

and i want to sum the marks column and display that in another pagein that controller

```
@exam_group = ExamGroup.find(params[:exam_group])
  @student = Student.find_by_id(params[:student])
  @batch = @student.batch
  @modules = StudentAdditionalField.find(:all)
  @total = Answer.sum(:marks)
  @exams = []
  @modules.each do |mod|
    @exams.push mod.name unless mod.name.nil?
    @exams.push mod.marks unless mod.marks.nil?
    @exams.push total unless total.nil?
  end
```

and display view is

```
      <% @exams.each do |es| %>
    <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
      <td class="col-1"> <%= es.name %></td>
        <td class="col-1"><%= es.marks || '-' %></td>
        <% total_marks_attained = @total %>
        <td class="col-1"><%= es.marks %></td>
        <% total_max_marks = @total %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Are you sure you need all those calls in your controller function? Rails has a standard of [thin controller, fat model](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-ruby-on-rails-best-practices/), which means that you should really use your controller as a simple guide to pull data from the models. In your case, it means that you should be using [relational database functionality](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to make a single call

Answer (score 0):

So from what you've posted, it seems that you need to use the [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) function of ActiveRecord:

```
Model.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).sum(:marks)
```

However, it looks like your code is not following rails conventions. Specifically, you're not making use of the ActiveRecord relations, such as `belongs_to` or `has_many`. If you made use of these, you'd literally be able to call `@user = User.find(current_user.id)` and you'll get all their marks like this: `@user.marks`